# ExtJS Classic 7.3.0: Renderer for checkbox column in grid is not showing a checkbox

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect

If I don't use renderer, checkbox is shown. If I use renderer, true/false value is shown. I need to do some processing in the renderer before setting the value to true/false, hence I need to use renderer.

Here is a fiddle explaining my issue: [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3ec5)

Edit: I have a model A that has an association of hasOne model B. And both these models load from a different store. The grid store has to be of model A, because that’s the main store. And the checkbox field is in model B. So to show the checkbox value, I use a renderer where I get the model B, and then need to set the checkbox value

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to do doesn't make too much sense. The point of renderer is to alter what will you put into the cell. As you used `checkcolumn` you asked the column to put a checkbox into to column instead of text/record value. If you add a renderer function to a `checkcolumn` you simply voids the `checkcolumn`'s default behaviour. If you really want this, simply add this to the end of your renderer function to see if fits your needs:

```
 return this.defaultRenderer(value);
```

But I really do think you are doing some anti-pattern there, and I would advise to rethink it, or try to explain it with a bit more detail.

Comment: Alright I think your solution works. But I’ve edited my question with why I’m trying to do this. Is there a better way for it?